# Typescript issues: Restricted property types incompatible

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm learning to use Typescript by applying it to a validation library I build.

types.ts

```
export type Value = string | boolean | number | null | undefined;
export type ExceptionResult = {
    __errorType: string;
    __errorArgs: string[];
};
export type ValidationResult =
    | [ExceptionResult]
    | [undefined, Value]
    | undefined;
export type Rules = {
    always: (defaultValue: Value) => (value: Value) => ValidationResult;
    [key: string]: (defaultValue: Value) => (value: Value) => ValidationResult;
};
```

String.ts

```
type ValueAlways = Extract<Value, string | undefined | null>;
type ValueOther = Extract<Value, string>;
export const rules: Rules = {
    always: (defaultValue: ValueAlways) => (value: ValueOther) => {
        if (defaultValue !== undefined && (value == null || defaultValue === value))
            return [undefined, defaultValue];
        if (typeof value !== "string" || value === "")
            return [Exception("String", [])];
    },
    equal: (mustBe: ValueOther) => (value: ValueOther) => {
        if (mustBe !== value) return [Exception("StringEqual", [mustBe])];
    },
}
```

Error message

```
Type '(defaultValue: ValueAll) => (value: ValueSpec) => [undefined, string | null] | [ExceptionResult] | undefined' is not assignable to type '(defaultValue: Value) => (value: Value) => ValidationResult'.
  Types of parameters 'defaultValue' and 'defaultValue' are incompatible.
    Type 'Value' is not assignable to type 'string | null | undefined'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | null | undefined'.ts(2322)
types.ts(9, 2): The expected type comes from property 'always' which is declared here on type 'Rules'
```

My idea was to have a `Value` type that encompasses all the types I support and `ValueAlways` and `ValueOther` types to restrict it to the type I'm using. However, it keeps complaining that Value and `ValueAlways` / `ValueOther` are incompatible.

Why is this occurring? Why is it complaining about `number`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that Function properties have to include all types of their prototype.

This is important because if you have a `Rule`, typescript may not know which kind, thus `Rules.always(12)` must always be correct - thus `rules.always(12)` must also be possible.

> You might be looking for [Conditional Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types) and/or [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) - But this really lies in your use case